# VBS function not executing when button is selected

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a VBScript that will allow me to select items from a drop down menu. If possible once an option is selected it will open a particular file or program. I'm not sure why it's not working? Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell
Dim aOpt(6)
aOpt(0) = "Option 1"
aOpt(1) = "Option 2" 
aOpt(2) = "Option 3"  
aOpt(3) = "Option 4" 
aOpt(4) = "Option 5" 
aOpt(5) = " "
aOpt(6) = " "
SelectBox "Select an install option", aOpt

Function SelectBox(sTitle, aOptions)
Dim oIE, s, item
  set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  With oIE
    .ToolBar   = False : .RegisterAsDropTarget = False
    .StatusBar = False : .Navigate("about:blank")
    While .Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
    With .document
      With .parentWindow
        if Instr(.navigator.appVersion, "MSIE 6") > 0 Then
          oIE.FullScreen = True
        End if
        oIE.width = 400 : oIE.height = 600
        oIE.left = .screen.width \ 2 - 200
        oIE.top  = .screen.height\ 2 - 75
      End With ' ParentWindow
      s = "<html><head><title>" & sTitle & " " & String(80, ".") _
        & "</title></head><script language=vbs>bWait=true</script>" _
        & "<body bgColor=Silver><center><b>" & sTitle & "<b><p>" _
        & "<select id=entries size=1 style='width:250px'>" _
        & "  <option selected>" & sTitle & "</option>"
      For each item in aOptions
        s = s & "  <option>" & item & "</option>"
      Next
      s = s & "  </select><p>" _
        & "<button id=but0 onclick='bWait=false'>OK</button>" _
        & "</center></body></html>"
      .WriteLn(s)
      With .body
        .scroll="no"
        .style.borderStyle = "outset"
        .style.borderWidth = "3px"
      End With ' Body
      .all.entries.focus
      oIE.Visible = True
      On Error Resume Next
      While .ParentWindow.bWait
        WScript.Sleep 100
        if oIE.Visible Then SelectBox = ""
        if Err Then Exit Function
      Wend ' Wait
      On Error Goto 0
      With .ParentWindow.entries
        SelectBox = .options(.selectedIndex).text
      End With
    End With ' document
    .Visible = False
  End With   ' IE
  Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.shell" )
      If aOptions = aOpt(0) Then
        objShell.Run("""Z:\folder\file""")
        Set objShell = Nothing
      End if
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

"It's not working" because

```
If aOptions = aOpt(0) Then
```

compares an array against an element of an other (?) array. By rights you should get an error message:

```
>> aOptions = Array()
>> If aOptions = "whatever" Then
>>    WScript.Echo "bingo"
>> End If
>>
Error Number:       13
Error Description:  Type mismatch
```

If not, you have disabled VBScript's error handling.